# How to find out the Page Download Time/Size in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, add-on, page-size

Is there any free tool for IE so that I can know the page download time and download size?

I'm using IE Web Developer tool but it doesn't show download time/size.

For FireFox, there is an [addon called Lori](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lori-life-of-request-info/) which does it.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the IE11 dev tools appears to be lacking that nice total time taken. To get around this, in IE11 you can export the data as a CSV. There is an export button next to the start/Stop button on the Network tab.

1. Open the CSV, observe that the times for each component are given in both milliseconds and seconds.
2. Add a new empty column next to the 'Taken' column.
3. Filter the Taken column to only show 'ms'.
4. Use the Text to columns feature to move the letters ms to the next column (make the delimiter a space. Note that < 1ms figures will move the 1 to the new column. So if you are being really granular then you need to find these and move the 1 back to the Taken column and remove the < that is in there.)
5. Use the SUM feature to get the total ms.
6. Repeat this process but this time for the seconds.

Convert your ms to seconds and add this figure to the total seconds and you will have your total page load time.

Answer (score 0):

[MySpace’s Performance Tracker](http://msfast.myspace.com/) works on IE 6 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Check again on IE developer tools. Hit F12, then click on the network tab and press the "Start Capturing" button.  That'll give you download time, size, sequence, and let you see the request and response headers/body.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the Network tab. Which version are you using? I'm using IE8 on Windows XP! It seems only IE 9.0+ has the Network tab.

Comment: Under IE8, look for the [Profiler tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565629(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: like OP @TheLight I'm also looking for "total page download time".  Seems like IE Developer tools is only showing per-request download times, but not total cumulative.  Chrome gives a nice summary "Load 1.96 seconds" at the bottom, but I can't seem to find the same thing in IE.

Answer (score -2):

just use the Google Chrome Developer tools when you press F12 in Google Chrome then go to network and refresh the page you need the size of and it will give you a graph with the size of each file referenced

Comment: Page load times depend on browser.  Using chrome to benchmark page load time on a different browser is not useful. Also, the question specifically states IE, so this answer is clearly incorrect.